# angular html 5 form validation breaks when I use ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, html, validation

I have a multi step angular form using ui.router. I have a form html file that loads each step as a view. Each step has a button with a ui-sref link that takes the user to the next step. However it wont show the html 5 validation hints unless I remove the ui-sref. How can I have the validation work while still triggering the ui-sref at the same time?

**my main form view:**

```
<form  ng-submit="processForm()" name="mortgage">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
        <div id="form-views" class="small-12 columns" ui-view></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**my view html:**

```
<h3>Please provide some information about your property</h3>
<label for="name">Zip Code</label>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{5}" class="form-control" name="zipcode" type="number" ng-model="formData.zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" required>
<button ui-sref="form.verify" type="submit" class="next">Next</button>
```

**my controller**

```
angular
  .module('angularApp', [
    'rzModule',
    'btford.modal'
    'ui.router'
  ])

  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/property-type');

     $stateProvider
    .state('form', {
        url: '/form',
        templateUrl: 'views/form.html',
        controller: 'FormCtrl'
    })
    .state('form.info', {
        url: '/property-info',
        templateUrl: 'views/property-info.html'
    })
    .state('form.verify', {
        url: '/property-verify',
        templateUrl: 'views/property-verify.html'
    })
    .controller('FormCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.processForm = function() {
            console.log($scope.formData);
        };
    });
```

Comment: you can change the ui-sref to ng-click and in the function do a $stage.go

Comment: also you can do a enable button if the form is $valid.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco thanks for the info. Unfortunately $state.go() still triggers even if invalid. I also tried adding ng-disabled if any field is invalid. This works in that it disables the button but it doesn't give any validation errors.